# Use of SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, ...) in a multi-process system

Tags: c, db2, odbc

I want to make sure I am implementing connections properly in a multi-process system.
Specifically, the environment handle.

SQLAllocHandle seems to be used by several database vendors.  My immediate interest is in DB2, but I would also like to know about how this is handled by other vendors.

The examples I find on the web allocate the environment handle, then immediately allocate the database handle.
I presume the examples are for single process systems so in that context they make sense.
Something like this **pseudo** code:

```
SQLHANDLE connenv = NULL;
SQLHANDLE conn = NULL;

int connectEnv(void)
{
   connenv = NULL;
   if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &connenv))
   {
      printf("Fail to allocate memory for connenv");
      return 0;
   }

   return 1;
}

int connectDbc(void)
{
   conn = NULL;

   if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, connenv, &conn))
   {
      SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, connenv);
      printf("Fail to connect to database");
      return 0;
   }

   if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLConnect(conn, conninfo, SQL_NTS, NULL, SQL_NTS, NULL, SQL_NTS))
   {
      printf("unable to allocate connection %s", conninfo);
      return 0;
   }
   return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   while (1) {
       waitForReasonToStartChild()
       if (fork()) {
          // parent process

       } else {
          // child process
          connectEnv();
          connectDbc();
       }
   }
}
```

To save time, I would like to move the allocation of the environment handle to the parent process and leave the database connection in the child process.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   connectEnv();
   while (1) {
       waitForReasonToStartChild()
       if (fork()) {
          // parent process

       } else {
          // child process
          connectDbc();
       }
   }
}
```

This just seems to make more sense to me (even if it was not faster), but I have not found examples on the web.

Is that the proper way to do it?
Are there other techniques that are better?

Answer (score 0):

The first link I found for multi-threading for DB2 ODBC has an example like your preferred approach.

The link is http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/SSEPEK_11.0.0/com.ibm.db2z11.doc.odbc/src/tpc/db2z_lethrd.html

To summarise, the parent thread allocates the environment, then each child thread (two in the example shown) allocates its own connection handle and uses it:

> 1. Creates two child Language Environment threads from an initial parent thread. The parent thread remains active for the duration of
>      the child threads. DB2 ODBC requires that the thread that establishes
>      the environment handle must persist for the duration of the
>      application. The persistence of this thread keeps DB2 language
>      interface routines resident in the Language Environment enclave.
> 2. Connects to database A with child Language Environment thread 1 and uses SQLFetch() to read data from this connection into a shared
>      application buffer.
> 3. Connects to database B with child Language Environment thread 2. Child Language Environment thread 2 concurrently reads data from the
>      shared application buffer and inserts this data into database B.
> 4. Calls Pthread functions to synchronize the use of the shared application buffer within each of the child threads.

Comment: This is a good answer with one quibble: I am using fork, not threads.  I am going to hold out on accepting this answer to see if someone will shed some light on how fork might be different.

Comment: For threads your preferred code is fine so long as the driver is thread safe (for ODBC 3 they all should be but a few are not). For forking I wouldn't do this as a) it will likely break if your parent exits/dies whilst a child is running b) allocating an environment is not an expensive process anyway c) there could be implications with connection pooling (although this could be a reason for actually doing what you want to do) d) you'd have to remember to not free the env handle in the child.